# Why is my output negative? I am multiplying 2 positive numbers?

Tags: c++, integer, integer-overflow

The expected output of the following program is the first perfect square number,  whose last two digits are both odd (WHICH DOES NOT EXIST). So instead of returning a blank screen (since such number doesn't exist), the output is -2147479015, which is NEGATIVE.

But the code is `cout << i*i`, which is obviously non-negative. I looked it up online and saw something about "overflow" but i am not quite understanding what overflow is. When I google it, all I get is overflow attacks , which is not what I want to know.

```
int main() {
    for(int i =1; ; i++) {
        if(i*i%2 !=0 && i*i/10%2 !=0) {
            cout << i*i;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What is overflow? Why is it causing me to get a negative number?

Comment: Consider using unsigned long long instead of int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numeric variables (like your "i", which is an "int") can only hold a limited range of numbers.  For the purposes of demonstrating, let's say that there are only four different numbers that an int can hold (obviously, a real int could hold a lot more than that).  Those numbers might be -2, -1, 0, and 1.

If I have an int whose value is 0, and I add 1 to it, I get an int whose value is 1.  But if I then add another 1, I do *not* get an int whose value is 2.  Remember, an int cannot possibly have the value 2.  It can only have the values -2, -1, 0, or 1.

So instead, 1 + 1 will "wrap around": When you go "past" the maximum possible value, it wraps back to the minimum possible value.  So 1 + 1 = -2.

That's "overflow".  What's happening to you is the same thing, but with multiplication rather than addition, and of course "int" having many, many more possible values than just four.

Comment: You have the right idea, but you should know that although common, signed integer overflow is not guaranteed to wrap around. It's undefined behavior, so anything can happen especially with modern compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Overflow means that the capacity of data type has been reached and overpassed. In the case of the data type `int` the most significant bit is reserved to indicate the negative value:

`(dec)2147483647 = (hex)0x7FFFFFFF`.

If you add 1 to the number 2147483647 the negative flag (`0x80000000`) will be activate.

From (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) I leave you an image with the limits to each data type:

[image]

Use `unsigned long long int` instead of `int` to have a wide range of positive and integer values.